# как добавить 0 код дням в календаре?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, datepicker

не работают 0 в от 1-9 в календаре тоесть все даты прдсвечиваются а вот все что от 1 до 9 нет я так понимаю нужен ноль но как его добавить в код что бы работало

```
("0" + curr_date).slice(-2)
```

я знаю есть такая функция, но она не работает

```js
 var active_dates = ["11/12/2016",  "13/12/2016", "01/01/2017", "15/01/2017", "16/01/2017"];
 
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy", 
   
   todayHighlight: true,
   maxViewMode: 0,
    beforeShowMonth: 1,
 

   beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var d = date;
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear() ;
            if(curr_month<10)curr_month = "0"+curr_month;
                if(curr_date<10)curr_date = "0"+curr_month;
    var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

      if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
       return {
       classes: 'booked '
       };
      }
     return;
    }
   });
```

```css
.booked{
 background: #F00!important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addLeadingZero (n) {
    return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const format = ( value, length ) => 
  `${"0".repeat(length - value.toString().length)}${value}`;

console.log(format(9, 2));
console.log(format(12, 2));
console.log(format(10, 3));
```

Тоже самое, но при помощи рекурсии -

```js
const format = ( value, length ) => 
  value.toString().length < length ? format( "0" + value.toString(), length ) : value;

console.log(format(9, 2));
console.log(format(12, 2));
console.log(format(10, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var active_dates = ["15/11/2016", "01/01/2017"];

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy", 
 todayHighlight: true,
   maxViewMode: 0,
    beforeShowMonth: 1,
  beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var d = date;
    var day = d.getDate()  ;
       var curr_date = "0" + day;
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
       var curr_month = "0" + month;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear() ;
         if (curr_date == 00) {
       curr_date = 10;
       }       
       if (curr_date.length > 2){
       curr_date = (curr_date).slice(1);
       }
     
       if (curr_month == 00) {
       curr_month = 12;
       }       
       if (curr_month.length > 2){
       curr_month = (curr_month).slice(1);
       }
     
    var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year
       
      if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
       return {
       classes: 'booked '
       };
      }
     return;
    }
   });
```

```css
.booked{
 background: #F00!important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://bsdp-assets.blackcherry.us/1.3.0/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
```